# How to validation a textbox just in owner block or fieldset? (HTML Controls)

Tags: html, asp.net

I want my validations works just in a block or fieldset.

```
<fieldset>
<legend>block</legend>
   <input placeholder="ID" id="txtID" type="text" value="" runat="server" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('please fill this')"/>
   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Ok" />
</fieldset>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

lol.
answer is:

```
<form action="#">
<fieldset>
   <legend>block</legend>
   <input placeholder="ID" id="txtID" type="text" value="" runat="server" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('please fill this')"/>
   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Ok" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```